# I woke up in morning or I woke up in 'the' morning, what is correct?

Tags: word-usage, usage, articles

Similarly I came to school or I came to the school, what is correct?

What is the correct usage of 'the' and when should it be used? I haven't understood it even after years of my experience with English language or should I say the English language?

Comment: What research have you done? You might start here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-articles?sort=votes

Answer (score 0):

The OED has many examples, most of which use the article (definite or indefinite), and there is a specific subsection relating to 'in the morning' as a phrase:

**e. in the morning: during the morning of the following day; tomorrow morning.**

- 1562   A. Brooke tr. M. Bandello Tragicall Hist. Romeus & Iuliet 73   Take there a letter, which as soone as he shall ryse, Present it in the morning to my louing fathers eyes.
- 1897   B. Stoker Dracula viii. 101   I am to leave in the morning and to go over to Jonathan,..and to bring him home.
- 1920   D. H. Lawrence Lost Girl x. 240   I shall go and see the lawyer in the morning.

There *is* a section that shows 'morning' used without the article, but this seems to be in specific prepositional or adverbial cases:

**c. In prepositional phrases (without article), as at (also †in, †on, before, till, etc.) morning, from morning till evening, from morning to night, etc. Also with adjective, forming adverbial phrases, as all (also each, every, next, etc.) morning. Cf. a-morning adv.**

- ▸?a1500   R. Henryson tr. Æsop Fables: Fox, Wolf, & Husbandman l. 2233 in Poems (1981) 85   His vse wes ay in morning to ryse air.
- 1611   Bible (King James) Lev. vi. 12   And the Priest shall burne wood on it euery morning, and lay the burnt offering..vpon it.
- 1968   D. Moraes My Son's Father i. 3   At morning the sea was a very pale, indolent colour.

---

As for 'school', again, several variations are permissible. A subsection of the OED entry for 'school' shows examples without the article:

**b. Without article. Frequently preceded by a preposition, as at school, to school, etc. Education in or attendance at such an institution.**

- 1600   Shakespeare Merchant of Venice iii. iv. 75   Men shall sweare I haue discontinued schoole aboue a twelue-moneth.
- 1845   Dickens Cricket on Hearth i. 25   She and I were girls at school together.
- 2000   Guelph (Ont.) Mercury (Nexis) 14 Oct. b1   The rain was coming down so hard that parents had to piggyback their kids home from school.

I think that having a look through dictionary entries for the words you're uncertain about should clear up your confusion.